# JPA entity has more than one objects of the same class

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

```
@Entity
public class A {

    //should be mapped by a                         
    public B b1;
    //should be mapped by a
    public B b2;

}

@Entity
public class B {
    @ManyToOne
    public A a;
}
```

Can I achieve something like this? 
I know that I can use `long b1_id` and `long b2_id` in `class A` but I just want to see if there is a way to use the object right away.
Basically, `class A` will have exactly 2 instances of `class B`. It is not in a collection so I can't use `@OneToMany`. 
`Class B` always map to a single A.

The db table should be something like this:

```
A
id | b1_id | b2_id

B
id | a_id
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that should be fine. Use the appropriate `filter` condition. Please refer [**Hibernate Filters**](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/filters.html) for further details.